# How to cancel CountDownTimer after an OnPause?

Tags: android, arraylist, countdowntimer

Hey im trying to add countdown timers to an arraylist but it is crashing. It is crashing once I try to add one countdowntimer . Was wondering is there anything I could do to fix it?

```
ArrayList<CountDownTimer> timers;

@Override

protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    toggleLock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Checker = new CountDownTimer(1200000, 60000)
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //does stuff
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                };
                Checker.start();
                                timers.add(Checker);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You should post the log of the crash so we can know what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to initialize the arraylist, so might be throwing null pointer exception.

```
timers=new ArrayList<CountDownTimer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your timers arraylist.

ex.

```
ArrayList<CountDownTimer> timers = new ArrayList<CountDownTimer>();
```